# StatsBase.sample() can't draw without replacement if FrequencyWeights() are provided

Tags: random, julia

I'm trying to sample without replacement using `StatsBase.sample()` in Julia. Because I have my data in the following form I can use my counts as `FrequencyWeights()`:

```
using StatsBase

data   = ["red", "blue", "green"]
counts = [2000, 2000, 1]

balls  = StatsBase.sample(data, FrequencyWeights(counts), 1000)
```

One problem with this is that `StatsBase.sample()` implicitly sets `replace=true` so this is possible:

```
countmap(balls)
Dict("blue"  => 478,
     "green" => 2,  # <= two green balls?
     "red"   => 520)
```

Explicitly setting `replace=false` throws an error.

```
balls  = StatsBase.sample(data, FrequencyWeights(counts), 1000, replace=false)

Cannot draw 3 samples from 1000 samples without replacement.

error(::String)@error.jl:33
var"#sample!#174"(::Bool, ::Bool, ::typeof(StatsBase.sample!), ::Random._GLOBAL_RNG, ::Vector{String}, ::StatsBase.FrequencyWeights{Int64, Int64, Vector{Int64}}, ::Vector{String})@sampling.jl:858
#sample#175@sampling.jl:871[inlined]
#sample#176@sampling.jl:874[inlined]
top-level scope@Local: 2[inlined]
```

Is my only solution here to reformat my data to a wide form like this? Because that seems very inefficient as my actual data set has a lot of counts.:

```
wide_data = [fill("red", 2000)..., fill("blue", 2000)..., "green"]
sample(wide_data, 1000, replace=false)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
function mysample(data::AbstractVector, counts::AbstractVector, n::Integer)
    @assert n <= sum(counts)
    @assert firstindex(data) == 1
    @assert firstindex(counts) == 1
    res = similar(data, n)
    fw = FrequencyWeights(copy(counts))
    for i in 1:n
        j = sample(axes(data, 1), fw)
        res[i] = data[j]
        fw.sum -= 1
        fw.values[j] -= 1
    end
    return res
end
```